# Distributed Counters / Likes or Votes for Suggestions & Security Rules

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've used the documented technique to implement a [Distributed Counter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) for likes on a post. Right now I'm not using `FieldValue.increment` but I increment it myself. Regardless of this detail, I find it highly suspicious that a user could just intercept the commit-request and change the number to increment and so change the likes in the database.

As I'm also collecting the likes in a collection (with documents per user), I was hoping I could write a security rule that checks if the counter `equals` the amount of documents of the collection (with the `get()` function) but I cannot read collections with it.

How is this problem solved (without cloud funcitons)? How do I make sure the counter is synchronous with the actual amount of likes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it a lot, I managed to come up with the following solution:

```
let suggestionRef = this.firestore.firestore.collection("suggestions").doc(suggestion.id);
let suggestionUpVotesOfUser = suggestionRef.collection('upvotes').doc(this.authService.userId);

let batch = this.firestore.firestore.batch();
let increment = 1;
if ((await suggestionUpVotesOfUser.get()).exists) {
    increment = -1;
    batch.delete(suggestionUpVotesOfUser);
} else {
    batch.set(suggestionUpVotesOfUser, {});
}
batch.update(suggestionRef, { upvotesCount: firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.increment(increment) });
batch.commit();
```

I was concerned, that an "evil client" could just update the votes without adding or deleting his own document.

So I came up with the following firestore rule for updating a suggestion (the rule for the upvotes-subcollection is fairly simple only allowing a user to add or delete his own document):

```
allow update: if 
  (
    request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['upvotesCount']) &&
    (
      (request.resource.data.upvotesCount == resource.data.upvotesCount + 1 && !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/suggestions/$(suggestion)/upvotes/$(request.auth.uid)) && existsAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/suggestions/$(suggestion)/upvotes/$(request.auth.uid)))
      || 
      (request.resource.data.upvotesCount == resource.data.upvotesCount - 1 && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/suggestions/$(suggestion)/upvotes/$(request.auth.uid)) && !existsAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/suggestions/$(suggestion)/upvotes/$(request.auth.uid)))
    )
  )         
);
```

This is to make sure, that a user can only increase/decrease the vote by 1 and only if the user is allowed to by adding or removing his upvote-document in the upvotes-subcollection accordingly.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen & TarikHuber: I'd really appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend to solve this is to have a collection of `likes` per `post` and user `uid` and to write a simple rule that a user can only add his `uid` into that collection if it equals his `uid`. That is a very basic security rule. The user could also only add and remoe his own `uid`.

To cound just crate a coud function that counts how many of those `uid`s are there for a specific post. You can here also use the "distributed" counter method.

The counting can't be secured without Cloud Functions. If the user can change the end result of the counting he could save there anything. You can only do it with cloud functions and the method above would be the most secure one.

Comment: I already did it exactly the way you described. The counting by counting UIDs I thought too but is highly inefficient (download unnecessary array of strings instead of just one number) and also doesn't adhere to privacy guidelines (client could see all UIDs that liked the post and maybe over time with analysis find out which UID belongs to another person).

Comment: "The counting can't be secured without Cloud Functions." That's actually not true. While not trivial, you can ensure that the counter only gets incremented when the user created the document with their UID, and that they can only create that document when they increment the counter.

Comment: Thx @Puf for the info. I did not know that's possible. Do you have any example of it or more detailed explanation? I would love to know more about it. Does it also ensure that the client side can't save any count result like incrementing by 10 and not by 1. Also how does it handle concurent increment events from the client side.

Comment: I would also be very interested in an example especially as the rule for incrementing the counter would be on another document as the document that's created with the UID. @TarikHuber: I guess the concurrency issue can be handled by transactions (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

Comment: I know that you can do it with transactions but imagine a lot of users likes a single post. Each transaction will fail and retry untill it is successful making the like for some users take quite a time. Maybe it's possible on the client side but there are so much more things to think of that I would always do it with cloud functions. You can't awaoid to use them in such projects so why should you but stones on your own way. Imagine making updates to such a logic on client side. Updates don't happen at all devices at the same time. A nightmare.